# Count Visit and Group them by Company

Tags: sql, t-sql

I created this T-Sql Query to give me how many visit for customer  and group them by company 
my Pronlem is my Query don't count only one visit  and don't Group by company

```
SELECT     COUNT(  VisitTracking.customerID) AS #VISIT
                , MAX(VisitTracking.visitID) AS visitID
                ,Customers.title AS Title
                ,Customers.customerID
                ,Customers.firstName AS "First Name" 
                ,Customers.LastName AS "Last Name"
                ,Company.companyName AS "Company Name"
                ,VisitTracking.DateVisited AS "Date Visited"
                ,VisitTracking.nextVisit AS "Next Visit"
FROM         VisitTracking INNER JOIN
                      Customers ON VisitTracking.customerID = Customers.customerID INNER JOIN
                      Company ON VisitTracking.companyID = Company.companyID
GROUP BY VisitTracking.companyID,Customers.customerID, VisitTracking.customerID, Customers.title, Customers.firstName, Customers.LastName, Company.companyName, VisitTracking.DateVisited,VisitTracking.nextVisit
```

Output 
[image]

what I want

```
2   29  Mr  2   Mike    Mike        N/A 2013-01-31  
1   28  Mr  2   Mike    Mike        Compudata   2013-01-31
```

Comment: I'm not understanding how you came to counts 1 and 2?  And which records do you want to keep?  Meaning, you're grouping by date_visited which has different values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is because you're using the field DataVisited, you should remove the field or do something like this.

```
SELECT     COUNT(  VisitTracking.customerID) AS #VISIT
                , MAX(VisitTracking.visitID) AS visitID
                ,Customers.title AS Title
                ,Customers.customerID
                ,Customers.firstName AS "First Name" 
                ,Customers.LastName AS "Last Name"
                ,Company.companyName AS "Company Name"
                ,MAX(VisitTracking.DateVisited) AS "Date Visited"
                ,VisitTracking.nextVisit AS "Next Visit"
FROM         VisitTracking INNER JOIN
                      Customers ON VisitTracking.customerID = Customers.customerID INNER JOIN
                      Company ON VisitTracking.companyID = Company.companyID
GROUP BY VisitTracking.companyID,Customers.customerID, VisitTracking.customerID, Customers.title, Customers.firstName, Customers.LastName, Company.companyName,VisitTracking.nextVisit
```